# How to show textaera input in new clarity forms

Tags: vmware-clarity

i am basically facing to issues one is in my form have three fields, one text input, date and textaera inputs. In clarity UI recent update (1.0) documentation i did't see how to use textaera input, how can i use it using angular ?

second issue is that the date picker control and label is not aligned properly with the remaining fields (i am add 'clr-row' in input-date-container tag it works fine).[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/clr-dg-test-6vrtcr?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is missing the Textarea implementation, see [the Textarea documentation here](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v1.0/textarea). The datepicker alignment is an open bug right now [here](https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/2970). Here is your updated form.

```
<form clrForm>
    <clr-date-container>
      <label>Date</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Full example" clrDate  name="three" required />
    </clr-date-container>

    <clr-input-container>
      <label>Input</label>
      <input clrInput placeholder="Fill me in, scotty!" name="name"/>
    </clr-input-container>

    <clr-textarea-container>
      <label>Textaera</label>
      <textarea clrTextarea rows="3" placeholder="text aera">
      </textarea>
    </clr-textarea-container>
  </form>
```